# iOS get contacts from Dynamics CRM API

Tags: ios, api, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365

I am developing an iPhone mobile app. In this I need to implement get contacts from Microsoft Dynamics CRM. I am done with login with Dynamics CRM but I am facing issue in get contacts API.

I am trying to call get contacts API in postman using the way mentioned in documentation but I am getting webpage code in response. If API will start working in postman then I can easily integrate it in my iOS app.

I am referring this link for postman setup: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/setup-postman-environment

This is screenshot of my postman collection error:https://drive.google.com/open?id=17T93QYKrNkGMmK2QTyaI2kcF1RPrIPs_

This is screenshot of variables I set in postman: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MFuGci4rJw1Q1RxwNI9fHiBStNy0Z5HI

So can you please help me to execute this get contact API in postman. I am not sure if I am passing wrong value of any parameter or the issue is something different.

Comment: Did you get a chance to verify my answer?

Answer (score 0):

seems that the URL parameter is off it should be the Dynamics 365 oganization URL only, like https://orgname.crm.dynamics.com and should be follow by api/data/v9.1/[entity name]

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, Marcelo AcostaDiaz Thank you for response, I have tried your suggestion but it's not working. There are any issue in `Headers` ? May you please suggest me. You may check this link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jcLdbEoF9E7DCD8XRv-VHG1YvBNqpiFc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are targeting Dynamics CRM online environment but the documentation you are following is for on-premise environment.

Please [refer & follow these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/setup-postman-environment#connect-with-your-common-data-service-environment) for configuring Postman to target CRM online by generating token using OAuth 2.0 authentication.

[image]